# Mean square convergence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $X_n(\omega) = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n\omega}\right)$ converges to $1$ in mean square. That is,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[(X_n -1)^2] = 0.$$

I can prove this by showing that $X_n$ converges to $1$ almost surely, which in turn, implies convergence in mean square. But, how can we prove the convergence in mean square in a more direct manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\rho(\omega)\ge 0$ be the density function over which the expectation is taken.

Note that $ \left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n\omega}\right)\right)^2\le 4$ and hence $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n\omega}\right)\right)^2\rho(\omega)\,d\omega\le 4\int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(\omega)\,d\omega=4<\infty$.

Therefore, the dominated convergence theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{E}\left[(X_n-1)^2\right]&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n\omega}\right)\right)^2\rho(\omega)\,d\omega\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n\omega}\right)\right)^2\rho(\omega)\,d\omega\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!